# How to make a color finding function with a hex color code in C++

Tags: c++, colors, hex

Im trying to take a hex color code and determine which color it is im only doing the five basic colors. This is my code to take rgb and return hex code.

```
string rgbtohex(int r, int g, int b, bool with_head)    //the following turns rgb values to hex values.
{
  stringstream ss;
  if (with_head)
  ss<< "#";
  ss<<hex<<(r << 16 | g << 8 | b );
  return ss.str();
}
```

I can output the hex code by using this

```
cout<<rgbtohex(r,b,g,true)<<endl;   //outputs hex color code
```

I want to make a function that will take the rgbtohex output and return the color. Something like this

```
string hextocolor()
{
 if(rgbtohex(r,g,b,true) = "#ff0000"){
 cout<<"Red"<<endl;
 }
}
```

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: How is it different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831588/trying-to-create-function-to-find-color-from-hex-color-code-c)?

Answer (score 0):

This would work for turning in to hex:

```
string rgbToHex(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b, bool withHead){
    stringstream ss;
    if (with_head)
        ss<< "#";
    
    ss << hex << r;
    ss << hex << g;
    ss << hex << b;

    return ss.str();
}
```

I think your original solution also worked, The problem is that you used `=` instead of `==` in your if statement in `hexToColor`.

Comment: You miss `std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')`, as black would be displayed as `#000` instead of `#000000`.

Answer (score 0):

With `std::map`, you might do something like

```
std::string toColorName(const std::string& hexColor)
{
    static const std::map<std::string, std::string> colors{
        {"#000000", "black"},
        {"#0000ff", "blue"},
        {"#00ff00", "green"},
        {"#ff0000", "red"},
        {"#ffffff", "white"}
    };
    return colors.at(hexColor);
}
```